# Copy event objects through the interface

Tags: c++, polymorphism, abstract-class

I am currently working on a little project and adding an event system. I'm trying to defer the events so that they can be handled in an event part of the update stage. But the problem is that I can't figure out how to copy or create an `Event*` from an `Event&`.

Here is a simplified version of the problem:

```
#include <list>
#include "Event.h"

std::list<Event*> queue;
Event* buffer;

void PushEvent(Event& e) {
    // Copy Event in to some ptr. (This is the code I don't know how to write)
    // It doesn't work because Event is an abstract type 
    Event* event = new Event(e);
    queue.push_back(event);
}

Event& PopEvent() {
    buffer = queue[0];
    queue.erase(0);
    return *buffer;
}

bool IsEmpty() {
    return queue.empty();
}
```

I would really like to keep the API the same, but I'm not sure how I can copy the reference.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At a glance `queue.push_back(&e)` seems like it would work, and then the bigger question is making sure the ownership semantics are being handled correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is that a base class does not know how to dynamically copy construct instances of its children. Instead, the `Event` interface will need to expose a common way for child classes to define how to copy themselves, an operation commonly called "cloning".

Here is an approach you could use:

```cpp
class Event {
...

public:
    virtual Event * clone() = 0;

...
}
```

Each child class must implement `clone` to return a copy of the current instance using their copy constructor:

```
class ChildEvent {
public:
    virtual ChildEvent * clone() {
        return new ChildEvent(*this);
    }

...
}
```

And then your use case would look like:

```
Event* event = e.clone();
```

(by the way, it's usually good to use `::std::unique_ptr<>()` in these cases rather than just returning a raw pointer, but I'll leave that up to you)

Comment: It's not at all clear to me that the intended behavior is to produce a copy of `e` and add it to `queue` when `PushEvent` is called. If `queue` is supposed to maintain ownership of the `Event`s it's collecting, `PopEvent` will have to be rewritten as well and would indeed probably be better off with `std::unique_ptr<Event>` instead of `Event*` raw pointers.

Comment: I had tried this method too but I can't remember where I went wrong. This definitely would solve my problem too. I am not sure anymore if I'll use this (I can just add it to my child event class macros) or if I will just change the API to accept unique pointers.

Comment: And then you can generate the clone method using CRTP.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that polymorphically copying the event objects is what you actually need (although that will work) but rather *transferring the ownership* of these event objects to and from the event queue.

Very likely, the events are generated somewhere and then stored in the event queue. Eventually, the events stored in the queue are extracted and delivered to other components that will handle them or forward them further to be consumed.

I would say that this transmission of `Event` objects and how their ownership is affected by moving them around is what you need to focus on.

---

First, I'd switch from `Event *` to `std::unique_ptr<Event>` in the queue to clearly state who owns the event objects:

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<Event>> queue;
```

This makes clear that `queue` owns the `Event` objects it holds.

`PushingEvent()` would take an `std::unique_ptr<Event>` instead of an `Event&`:

```
void PushEvent(std::unique_ptr<Event> event) {
   queue.push_back(std::move(event));
}
```

The *caller* to this function initially owns the `Event` object but must transfer the ownership to this function when calling it. Then, `PushEvent()`, in turn, transfers the ownership of the `Event` to the event queue by further moving the `std::unique_ptr<Event>` into the queue.

Similarly with `PopEvent()` – just in the opposite direction:

```
[[nodiscard]] std::unique_ptr<Event> PopEvent() {
   auto event = std::move(queue.front());
   queue.pop_front();
   return event;
}
```

The event queue initially owns the `Event` object to pop. It transfers the event's ownership from the queue to the function itself through the local variable `event`. Finally, the ownership is further transferred to the *caller* to `PopEvent()` by returning an `std::unique_ptr<Event>` by value.

Comment: I was really hoping to keep the API the same which is why I didn't use this method, but I suppose it's probably a bad idea to not use smart pointers here. I had tried this, I just didn't accept that I would have to accept a smart pointer as the input too. I'll use this method.

Comment: @James51332 Note that there is no real need for a virtual constructor in your original design – you can just copy the (raw) pointers. You can still do it without smart pointers by storing `Event *` in the event queue and taking and returning `Event&` for `PushEvent()` and `PopEvent()`, respectively. However, you will need a lot of discipline for managing the lifetime of the pointed objects. `std::unique_ptr<Event>` automatically handles that for you.

Comment: I was overly hesitant to accept this because I always feel like `unique_ptr` should have more overhead. I have thought about it and decided it's honestly not going to have any impact on performance and probably save my computer a few memory leaks.

Comment: @James51332 An `std::unique_ptr` without an special deleter function has [almost no overhead](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/memory-and-performance-overhead-of-smart-pointer) over a raw pointer.

Comment: I know that but it just feels weird. Thanks for the help I just got it working too!